# Is the empty set finite in the sense of Tarski?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The answers provided so far seem to rely on numerical approaches, but set theory transcends number theory.  So who can provide an answer that does not depend on a development of the cardinals or ordinals?

Hint: Tarski's definition of a finite set is as follows "A set is finite if and only if every non-empty family of its subsets has a minimal element."

This definition can be shown to be equivalent to definitions given by Russell, Zermello, Dedekind, Sierpinski, and Kuratowski.

Comment: You wrote the definition. So you have your answer: [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: What does it mean to be a minimal element in a family of sets?

Comment: Not vacuous because the empty set is a subset of the empty set.

Comment: @BarryCipra https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207308/a-set-a-is-finite-if-and-only-if-every-nonempty-set-of-subsets-of-a-has-a-m/3207321

Comment: @xxxx0xxxx Ah, yes. But close :) The empty set is the minimal element of the family formed by itself.

Comment: @xxxx0xxxx: Vacuous because the one element set always has minimal (and maximal) elements under any ordering.

Comment: Good question, answer: A minimal element would be one in which no other members of the family are a proper subset.

Comment: There is only one non-empty family of subsets of the empty set. It has a minimal element. Done.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent, Servaes and Jean-Claude Arbaut had the answer promptly...

The only family of non-empty subsets is $\{\emptyset\}$, and $\emptyset$ is both a minimal and maximal element under '$\subset$'

Comment: And also Stinking Bishop,  where were y'all when this question was tortured six years ago?

Comment: You summarised the points from the comments brilliantly yourselves - I don't think there is need for another summary (of mine). Thanks!